# The sum of the second numbers in the first 100 rows of Pascal's Triangle

Tags: combinatorics

What is the sum of the second numbers in the first $100$ rows of Pascal's triangle (excluding the first row, the row containing a single $1$)? The sum should be over the second through the hundredth row.

How would I solve this? I don't know where to start.

Comment: Would the first few be 0,1,2,3,4,...?

Comment: $\;5,050\;$${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$ ....Beginning with $\;k=1\;$

Comment: i'm told that 5050 is incorrect. I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

The second binomial coefficient in row n° $k$ is $\dbinom{k-1}1=k-1$.